# Catch browser closing event in safari running in iPhone, iPad etc

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

How do i capture the browser closing event in safari running in iPhone ,iPad, itouch etc. as the onbeforeunload event will not work with safari?

Many thanks,
Hariprasath

Answer (score 1):

Safari for iOS supports the **unload** event, which should do the trick. You can find out more information about supported Safari for iOS events here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: unload event doesnt seem to be working for me when i tested my application from an iPhone. Why i'm facing this problem? Is there any other way i can use to catch the browser close event.... Typically onbeforeunload is not working with safari running on iPhone, iPad etc..

Comment: Could you post the code you are using, and I will take a look at it for you?

Comment: window.unload = function () {
//logic goes here


    };

Comment: Is the **unload** attribute attached to the <body> tag?

Comment: This has word for me in the past: function load() {
 

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(‘safari’)!=-1) {
 

var bodyElt;
 bodyElt = document.getElementById(“www-rd2inc-com”);
 
if (!bodyElt) {
 

bodyElt = document.getElementsByTagName(“body”)[0];
 
}
 

if (bodyElt) {
 

bodyElt.addEventListener(“unload”, unload_handler, false);
 
}
 

} else {
 

window.onunload=unload_handler;
 
}
 
}

Comment: and how will the unload_handler look like? can yu post that as well?

Comment: the unload event doesnt seems to be fired in the iPhone.. is there any other way around?

Comment: Even I have the same problem but the solution which Richard Grey has posted does not work at all. I checked in Apple forums but no luck. Here is the discussion forum from Apple https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2137780?threadID=2137780 No one has responded to this type of issue, dont know how to handle. Thanks,
Vivek