# javascript detect if iphone browser closes

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm trying to detect if on ios (or any other mobile device for that matter) goes into background mode.

onblur doesn't seem to fire.

I was just wondering if there was another method I could use.

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792519/catch-browser-closing-event-in-safari-running-in-iphone-ipad-etc

Comment: When you close the browser. It is still actually running in the background. Unless you double tap the home button and remove it from running in the background